# Освіжаючі, освіжальні, освіжні: якій формі надати перевагу?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, прикметники

Прошу вашої аргументації щодо вживання/невживання відповідних форм.

Мене цікавить аргументація за/проти використання суфіксальних форм. 
На даний момент я вважаю надання переваги використанню/невикористанню суфіксів -уч-/-юч- справою смаку, не більш за те.

Comment: Теґ [tag:вибір-слова] передбачає: «Запитання має містити **чітко обумовлений контекст** і щонайменш приблизний список слів-кандидатів»

Comment: @bytebuster, загалом, якщо чесно, по-моєму, було б непогано, якби запитання типу «у яких контекстах яке з цих слів краще застосовувати» теж мали право на існування, коли вони не потребують наддовгої відповіді, але я вже втомився відстоювати/просувати свої погляди, вважаймо, що я цього не казав.

Comment: @Sasha, для цього вже є [tag:різниця-між-словами] та [tag:значення-слів]. Let's go, я створив! © :-) Тому не варто боротися з вітряками. Якщо авторка мала на увазі інший теґ і іншу мету запитання, то це треба відобразити в [edit]. А я тоді вже шукатиму недоліки відносно нових заявлених теґів. :-) Зараз запитання, безумовно, є сире і заслуговує на щось із діапазону відредагувати / закрити / видалити+переосмислити+запитати_як_слід. Не сумніваюся, що ми маємо на сайті прихильників першого методу, від яких я очікую **практичних дій** з порятунку цього запитання.

Comment: @bytebuster, якщо чесно, я, як відвідувач, інтуїтивно не відчуваю різниці між [tag:різниця-між-словами] і [tag:вибір-слова] — на перший погляд здається, що вони синонімічні. Трішки подумавши, я збагнув, що [tag:вибір-слова] — це про вибір слова _під конкретну ситуацію_, а [tag:різниця-між-словами] — це, мабуть, про порівняння слів _незалежно від контексту_, — але це зовсім неочевидно, як мінімум — треба було б в описі [tag:вибір-слова] додати згадку про [tag:різниця-між-словами], а як максимум — перейменувати [tag:вибір-слова] чи таки подумати про те, щоб відмовитися від жорсткого розділення.

Comment: @Sasha, я приблизно так само бачу цю відмінність. Але наші теґи „are not carved in stone“. Ніщо не заважає запропонувати і втілити кращу систему.

Comment: @bytebuster мене цілком влаштовує відповідь користувача Sasha і абсолютно не влаштовує бажання знищувати запитання. Є якийсь спосіб зупиняти таких бажаючих?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ці слова мають трішки різне значення:

- *освіжаючий* ≈ *освіжуючий* ≈ *освіжний* — той, що освіжає (освіжує);
- *освіжальний* ≈ *освіжувальний* — той, що *призначений для* освіження (освіжання, освіжування).

Тобто зазвичай Ви не можете сказати *освіж(ув)альний* про якесь природне явище, наприклад, *вітер* (якщо, звісно, воно не було штучно створено людьми з цією метою). Речі, штучно створені людьми з цією метою, навпаки, влучніше описувати словами з 2-ї групи, хоча слова з 1-ї групи в широкому значенні теж для цього придатні, на мій погляд.

Представлення в корпусах і словниках:

- Група *освіжаючий* ≈ *освіжуючий* ≈ *освіжний*:

  - *освіжаючий* — [195 у ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87.*), [є в СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/osvizhajuchyj), [є в СУO](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/);
  - *освіжуючий* — [12 у ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87.*), [є в СУO лише прислівник *освіжуюче*](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/);
  - *освіжний* — [8 у ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD.*), [є в СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/osvizhnyj), [є в СУO](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).
- Група *освіжальний* ≈ *освіжувальний*:

  - *освіжальний* — [2 в ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD.*);
  - *освіжувальний* — [0 у ГРАК](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=wordrow&word=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD.*) (але є в Інтернеті).

Щодо вибору між *освіжаючий* (*освіжуючий*) й *освіжний* мовознавці неодноразово «схрещували шпаги». Дехто вважає, що словам на *-учий* (*-ючий*) в українській мові нема місця; дехто вважає, що нема місця лише активним дієприкметникам, але деякі найбільш уживані слова на *-учий* (*-ючий*) можна вважати не дієприкметниками, а віддієслівними прикметниками (принаймні, коли вони використовуються без залежних слів); дехто вважає, що активні дієприкметники непритаманні лише народно-поетичній мові, але цілком припустимі в науковомі стилі.

<sub>P.S.: Якщо хтось знайде старі обговорення (на цьому сайти чи на інших) стосовно двох тем:

(1) семантика різних суфіксів (зокрема *-н-* й *-альн-*),

(2) доречність слів на *-учий* (*-ючий*)

— і додасть сюди, буду радий (просто не маю часу).</sub>

P.P.S.: Щодо того, якому, власне слову надати перевагу… Вибір між 1-ю (*освіжаючий* ≈ *освіжуючий* ≈ *освіжний*) і 2-ю (*освіжальний* ≈ *освіжувальний*) групами, як я вже писав, має відбуватися на основі значення, яке треба передати. Вибір між дієприкметникоподібними словами (*освіжаючий*, *освіжуючий*) і «чистими» прикметниками (*освіжний*) залежить від вашого ставлення до форм на *-учий* (*-ючий*). Також зазначу, що від *освіжати* походять *освіжаючий* і *освіжальний*, а від *освіжувати* походять *освіжуючий* і *освіжувальний* — якщо ви розрізняєте [протяжні й наворотні](/q/4049) дієслова, то це остаточно визначить ваш вибір.

Comment: У запитанні написано: «якій формі надати перевагу?» Чи можна відредагувати цю відповідь, щоб вона відповідала на поставлене запитання?

Comment: До тих, хто поставив мінус, — цікаво було б дізнатися причину.

Comment: @bytebuster мене влаштовує ЦЯ відповідь.

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka, я трішки доповнив відповідь після коментаря bytebuster, тож тепер, сподіваюся, він уже не має нарікань.

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka, до речі, якщо Вас влаштовує відповідь, Вам слід натиснути ✓, щоб прийняти її. (Це стосується і попередніх Ваших запитань теж.)

Comment: @Sasha а як це вплине на подальше можливе коментування?

Comment: @OlenaLisovs'ka, технічно наявність/відсутність у запитання ухваленої відповіді ні на що не впливає (нові відповіді й коментарі можна створювати в будь-якому разі; і в будь-який момент отой значок ухвалення можна скасувати або перенести на іншу відповідь). Але психологічно хтось може бути більш зацікавлений відповідати на запитання без ухваленої відповіді (але також хтось психологічно може бути зацікавлений відповідати лише на запитання зовсім без відповідей — це ж не привід їх не писати; а когось, може, навпаки, заохочує «о, там написали/ухвалили неправильну/неточну в., зараз я їм покажу!»).